# Intuition behind adherent, limit, and isolated points in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, intuition

What is the intuition behind these three points in a topological space. Can you provide a diagram also, preferably in the plane.

Def. Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$, and $x \in X$. Then, x is an *adherent* point of $A$ iff. every open neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$.

Def. Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$, and $x \in X$. Then, x is a *limit* point of $A$ iff. every open neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ distinct of $x$.

Def. Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$, and $x \in X$. Then, x is an *isolated* point of $A$ iff. there is an open neighborhood of $x$ containing no points of $A$ other than $x$.

So as I understand it, an adherent point can be in $A$ but does not have to be. Thus, if I were to draw a set in the plane, then all the adherent points would be the interior united with the boundary? Is my intuition correct here? Diagrammatically speaking.

Then, a limit point is an adherent point but not conversely. Taking the plane again and an arbitrary set in the plane, then intuitively are the limit points those points inside the set but not on the boundary?

And then the isolated points in the plane would be all points on the boundary? Or perhaps boundary and exterior?

I can't seem to figure the two-dimensional intuition behind these points even though I can work with the definitions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

To answer your questions: (i) $\bar{A}=\mathring{A}\sqcup\partial A$ is true. this is in fact how we define the boundary $\partial A$ in general; (ii) all limit points are adherent points; (iii) a point is a limit point if and only if it is not an isolated point (whether or not it's contained in $A$) (this is a great exercise of taking the negation of a proposition by sending $\forall\rightarrow\exists$ and vice versa); (iv) those points inside the set but not in the boundary are called interior points; (v) those points inside the boundary but not in the set are limit points, but the converse is not true (there are limit points contained in the set);  (vi) points on the exterior of the closure of $A$ are isolated points, but the converse is not true. there are isolated points contained in $A$.

Comment: But let us suppose that my set $A$ is some shape in the plane i.e. a rectangle or some closed curve. Now, $A$ can be open. or closed (since we are in the plane and the only sets that are both are the empty set and the plane itself). What are then the isolated and limit points? So if I take the entire plane as a rectangle and inside of it a set $A$ what are these points then?

Comment: I would need more precision of the set $A$ to answer that question. If $A$ is the union of the three segments of the triangles, then its adherent and limit points are the set itself, and it doesn't have any isolated point.
There is no general intuition. You'll gain intuition by considering case by case. I would advise spending each day 20-25 minutes, picking up set you want and solve for these points by the definition. After one week you'll have intuition (or you'll doubt everything you know and don't know what is what anymore, haha).

Comment: That is what I thought. Because every time I find a geometric picture and I try to apply it I find a different example which then shows that my picture is wrong. But how  can I memorize these definitions then if not by intuition? I mean I know that the interior, boundary and exterior of a set are. I draw a set in the plane. Perhaps I am relying too much on my metric space intuition where we have the concept of a distance.

Comment: Try using separately each one of these concepts (in order not to confuse them neither). Personally I just do exercise and invent exercise and believe that with time, things'll become natural.

Answer (score 0):

Adherent points are either limit points or isolated points. Consider the set $X = (2, 3) \cup \{6\}$.

If $y$ is an isolated point of $X$, then $y\in X$ and we must be able to find an open neighborhood that contains $y$ but no other element of $X$. So in the example above, $y = \{6\}$ is an isolated point because we can find an interval, say $I = (5,7)$, which contains $I$ but no other element of $X$.

If $y$ is a limit point of $X$, then *each one* of the open neighborhoods that contain it must also contain some point of $X$ that is not equal to $y$. So any points in the interval $I = [2,3]$ are limit points of $X$. The limit point of a set may or may not be a member of it. The point $\{2.5\}\in X$ but $\{2\} \not\in X$, but both are limit points.

> if I were to draw a set in the plane, then all the adherent points would be the interior united with the boundary? Is my intuition correct here?

It's close. Let's look at the points inside (but not on the boundary of) a circle at the origin with radius 1 and some weird point outside the circle such as $(3,3)$. The interior points and the ones right on the boundary are the limit points of the circle, since even the smallest open neighborhood containing them must overlap or be in the circle. In this case, the limit points *nearly* capture the closure of the circle, but we also have to consider the isolated point $(3,3)$. When we look at the union of the limit and isolated points, we get all the adherent points, which make up the closure of the circle. Adherent points are also called *closure points*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so annoyed that no one explicitly tells that in a set of continuous interval or ball, either open or close, has its limit points the same with its adherent points. Limit points and adherent points differ only when the set has isolated points.

Consider the set $S = (2, 3) \cup \{6\}$.

$\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ are limit points and also adherent points, and of course all points in $(2, 3)$ are limit points and also adherent points, because their neighborhood contains infinite number of points from the set $S$ including and not including themselves.

$\{6\}$ is an isolated point because there is a neighborhood contains no point at all from the set $S$.

$\{6\}$ is not a limit point because there is a neighborhood contains no points from the set $S$ other than $\{6\}$ itself.

But $\{6\}$ is an adherent point because there is a neighborhood contains exactly one point from the set $S$ which is $\{6\}$ itself.